# Variable not hashing correctly

Tags: php, md5

I'm really hoping someone can help me out, I'm a noob so apologies for ignorance/stupidity in advance.

I'm trying to redirect users where than can pay with their card, I'm only having trouble setting the $amount. It works fine being set to a fixed amount ($amount="8000") however when it's set to $price it doesn't work and nothing is received on their side. Eventually I want to set $price in the bottom form however it doesn't work with it set to a fixed amount either. (as below)

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

```
 <?php
    //Replace these with the values you receive from Global Iris
    $merchantid = "XXXXX";
    $secret = "XXXXX";

    //The code below is used to create the timestamp format required by Global Iris
    $timestamp = strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S");
    mt_srand((double)microtime()*1000000);

    $orderid = $timestamp."-".mt_rand(1, 999);

    $curr = "GBP";
    $amount = $price * 100;
    $price = 80;

    /*-----------------------------------------------
    Below is the code for creating the digital signature using the MD5 algorithm provided
    by PHP. you can use the SHA1 algorithm alternatively. 
    */
    $tmp = "$timestamp.$merchantid.$orderid.$amount.$curr";
    $md5hash = md5($tmp);
    $tmp = "$md5hash.$secret";
    $md5hash = md5($tmp);

    ?>


    <!-- Prices for Global Iris -->
    <br />
    <br />
        <form action="https://redirect.globaliris.com/epage.cgi" method=post class="select">

    <input type=hidden name="MERCHANT_ID" value="<?=$merchantid?>">
    <input type=hidden name="ORDER_ID" value="<?=$orderid?>">
    <input type=hidden name="CURRENCY" value="<?=$curr?>">
    <input type=hidden name="AMOUNT" value="<?=$amount?>">
    <input type=hidden name="TIMESTAMP" value="<?=$timestamp?>">
    <input type=hidden name="MD5HASH" value="<?=$md5hash?>">
    <input type=hidden name="AUTO_SETTLE_FLAG" value="1">

    <select name="price" id="mySelect" onchange="return show_price(this.value);">
    <option value="100">Option 1 (£100)</option>
    <option value="120">Option 2 (£120)</option>
    <option value="115">Option 3 (£115)</option>
    <option value="135">Option 4 (£135)</option>
    <option value="80" >Option 5 (£80)</option>
    </select> 
    <br />
    <br />
    <input type=submit value="Proceed to secure server">
    </form>

            <div class="java">&pound; <span id="price_sp"><span></div>
    <script>
        function show_price(price)
        {
            document.getElementById('price_sp').innerHTML = price;
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of lines in the wrong order, `$price` needs to be set before it's used in the `$amount` calculation like so:

```
$price = 80;
$amount = $price * 100;
```

Further, you could edit the form as follows to submit the amount based on the dropdown value:

```
<select name="amount" id="mySelect" onchange="return show_price(this.value);">
<option value="10000">Option 1 (£100)</option>
<option value="12000">Option 2 (£120)</option>
<option value="11500">Option 3 (£115)</option>
<option value="13500">Option 4 (£135)</option>
<option value="8000" >Option 5 (£80)</option>
</select> 
<br />
<br />
<input type=submit value="Proceed to secure server">
</form>

        <div class="java">&pound; <span id="price_sp"><span></div>
<script>
    function show_price(price)
    {
        document.getElementById('price_sp').innerHTML = price/100;
    }
</script>
```

I've changed the field name to "amount" so it submits correctly (you would need to remove the hidden amount field) and then updated the value to submit in pence and added a division to the Javascript so it still reads nicely in the HTML output.